# How to modify a gray cmap with reserved false color?

Tags: python, image, matplotlib

Suppose a 256 grayscaled image,

How to modify the color map plt.cm.gray so that pixels of given gray value appear in a given color(red, blue ...). For example how to set pixels of value=1 to red and pixels of value=2 to green?

I'm aware of [masked array example](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/image_masked.html). But in that example, it seems that only one color can be set up.

I try to generate a custom cmap "agrey" (which failed):

```
## try to make a custom cmap
Ngrey = 256
a = np.linspace(0,1,num=Ngrey, endpoint=True)
A = np.array((a,a,a)).transpose()

#Set pixel with greylevel=1 to red
A[1,1:3]=0

col_dict = {'red':A,'green':A, 'blue':A}
print col_dict['blue'].shape
agrey = LinearSegmentedColormap('mygray', col_dict)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are dealing in a discrete grey scale anyway, instead of using `LinearSegmentedColormap`, you could use a `ListedColormap`, where you define your 256 grey values and then overwrite the values that you want coloured. Below a minimal example with a random picture:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
import numpy as np

pic = np.random.randint(256, size=(100,100))

Ngrey = 256
greys = np.linspace(0,1,Ngrey)

colors = [[g,g,g] for g in greys]

red = [1,0,0]
green = [0,1,0]
blue = [0,0,1]

colors[5] = red
colors[100] = blue
colors[200] = green

mymap=ListedColormap(colors)

plt.matshow(pic, cmap=mymap)
plt.show()
```

The result then looks something like this:[image: random grey scale image with certain, discrete values coloured in red, green, and blue]

Tested on `Python 3.5`